# Write the piecewise function in terms of unit step functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Write the piecewise function**

$f(t) = \begin{cases} 
      2t, &   0\leq t < 3 \\
      6,  &   3 \le t < 5 \\
      2t, &   t \ge 5 \\
   \end{cases}
 $

**in terms of unit step functions.**

So here is what i;ve got just guessing , I don't think i'm correct. I really need some help. But I got:

$f(t) = 2t[u(t-0) - u(t-3)] + 6[u(t-3) - u(t-5)] + 2t[u(t-5) - u(t - \infty)]$

Which becomes

$f(t) = 2t[u(t) - u(t-3)] + 6[u(t-3) - u(t-5)] + 2t[u(t-5)]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is correct, verified by teacher.

$f(t) = 2t[u(t) - u(t-3)] + 6[u(t-3) - u(t-5)] + 2t[u(t-5)]$

Comment: See https://imgur.com/a/dcy21 for an explanation of the procedure.