# Changing from inequality, to unit step to laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking to take this inequality, change it to a unit step function then use the Laplace transform table to convert it again.

$ f(t) = \{1, 0\le t<1\} $, $\{0, t\ge1\} $

Comment: See if this helps: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221663/write-the-piecewise-function-in-terms-of-unit-step-functions

Comment: @Moo  I have updated a answer for this question