# How do I get rid of the unit step function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

- I have an application problem that gives me a tank, and it says that at one point valve 'A' is open and is pouring in a brine solution with a salt concentration.
- Then after 5 minutes this valve is closed and valve 'B' begins to pour in a brine solution with a different salt concentration.
- The ultimate goal was to **find the concentration of salt in the tank as a function of time**.

I set this problem up using unit steps, and ( according to my professor ) the final solution I got was correct, except for one thing: I still had a unit function.

But I don't know how to get rid of it and the only feedback she gave to me was '???'.

Here is my solution:
$$
\mathrm{k}\left(\,t\,\right) = 
200 - 100\exp\left(\,{-\,{t\over 100}}\,\right) +
300\,\mathrm{u}\left(\,t - 5\,\right)
\left[\,1 - \exp\left(\,{-\,{t - 5\over 100}}\,\right)\,\right]
$$
I understand that the $\,\mathrm{u}\left(\,t - 5\,\right)$ shouldn't be in there, but I'm not sure what to do with it. What am I missing ?.

Comment: Can you write $k(t)$ as a piecewise function?

Comment: @Moo Do you mean am I able to write it as one, or do I know how to write it as one? I'm not sure if that's supposed to be in the final solution, and I'm also not sure how I would write it as a piecewise function.

Comment: If you are saying the result is wrong with the unit step, that is one thing. If you don't want to see the unit step function in the solution, you can write $k(t)$ as a piecewise defined function. See if you can follow and go in both directions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221663/write-the-piecewise-function-in-terms-of-unit-step-functions. Do you think the result is wrong after she said it was correct?

Comment: @Moo If the only way to write the equation and be rid of the unit step is to write it as a piecewise function then that would be the correct answer.

Comment: So, follow the example and see if you can go in both directions, easy to check by plotting each. Also, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022536/using-laplace-transforms-to-solve-a-piecewise-defined-function-initial-value-pro

Comment: Is $k(t)$ the quantity of salt (pounds) at time $t$ or is it the concentration of salt (pounds per gallon) at time $t4? Why don't you give us the whole problem, so we can tell if your answer is right or wrong? The initial conditions, the concentration and rate of flow from valve A, concentration and rate of flow from valve B, rate of flow at the exit valve if any?

Comment: When $t<5$ the second term vanishes, then $t>5$, $u(t-5)=1$ and the second term simplifies and combines with the first. Write that as a piecewise function.

Comment: It's possible that what the professor actually meant is that you only had one unit function, (doing some reasonable assumptions) from what you describe of the problem you actually need 2 unit steps functions.

Comment: either that or that is a hint for getting rid of the unit step (I hardly doubt you can't get rid of it according to some general assumptions I made)

Comment: The 2 unit steps are $u(5-t)$ this represents the time the valve A is open and gets closed, and $u(t-5)$ this will be the time when valve B starts pouring.